# Backface culling with semi-transparent material (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I'm trying to replicate the material I had in EEVEE.

[image: EEVEE render]

In cycles I get this.

[image: Cycles Render]

Any backface culling option I use doesn't change anything. I have tried to add into the shader by using the backfacing/geometry node data to make backfaces fully transparent but it doesn't work.

[image: Backface culling node setup]

The only way I can get what I want is to manually delete the backface.

[image: Cycles render with backfaces manually deleted]

I have tried volume but it is much too soft.

How can I get that EEVEE look? I'm confident I've tried all ways of deleting the backface but its something to do with the semitransparency.